# Arrange multiple correlation matrices plot into one figure

Tags: r

I am using R package `ellipse` to visualize correlations. My question is how to put 6 different correlation plots into one figure? I have tried to

1. use `par(mfrow=c(3,2), mar=c(3.1, 4.1, 2.1, 5.1))`, which works but I can only see 6 small groups of figures.
2. use `grid.arrange` which gives me error messages

   `Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
     input must be grobs!`

Is there a way to solve this issue? Thanks!

Here is my sample code

```
colors <- c("#A50F15","#DE2D26","#FB6A4A","#FCAE91","#FEE5D9","white",
            "#EFF3FF","#BDD7E7","#6BAED6","#3182BD","#08519C")


tiff(file = "Fig7.tiff", width = 10000, height = 8000, units = "px", res = 800, compression = "lzw") #
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

for (i in 1:6){

  plotcorr(cor(replicate(10, rnorm(10))), col=colors[5*cor(replicate(10, rnorm(10))) + 6], numbers = TRUE)
  plotcorr(cor(replicate(10, rnorm(10))), col=colors[5*cor(replicate(10, rnorm(10))) + 6], numbers = TRUE)  
}

dev.off()
```

I figured it out by modifying the margin. Thanks again!

```
  plotcorr(eval(parse(text=cor_name_app)), col=colors[5*eval(parse(text=cor_name_app)) + 6],  mar = 0.1 + c(0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2))
```

Comment: MWE -> data and code would help us diagnosis your problem

Comment: Please create a reproducible example of your first question, and show us what you do not like, and what you would like to have. Your second question has something to do with grid vs normal graphics, please see my answer.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it instead of editing it into your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to consider the `lattice` option. Look at the "corrgram" option in example 13.5 of Sarkar's Lattice book: http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In regard to the second problem, I think ellipse uses standard graphics. `grid.arrange` uses `grid` graphics, which do not work with standard graphics. The error you get is because of this incompatibility.

Comment: So I have to adjust the margin in the first approach? Thanks!

Comment: That would be an option, but I haven't seen your example so I do not know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by modifying the margin. Thanks again!

```
  plotcorr(eval(parse(text=cor_name_app)), col=colors[5*eval(parse(text=cor_name_app)) + 6],  mar = 0.1 + c(0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2))
```